# How to play multiple audio sources from one game object in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

So I have made questions already and the program knows when the question is answered correctly. I want it to play a sound when the question is answered correctly and another sound when the question is answered incorrectly. I have one game object called Managers that manages all of the UI Elements. However, when I get a question correct, it plays the incorrect music clip, and when I get an answer incorrect, it plays the incorrect music clip as well. Here's the code:

```
    void Start()
    {
      MusicSource.clip = MusicClip;
      MusicSource_2.clip = MusicClip_2;
    }

    public AudioSource MusicSource;
    public AudioClip MusicClip;
    public AudioSource MusicSource_2;
    public AudioClip MusicClip_2;
    void UpdateResolutionUI(ResolutionScreenType type, int score)
       {
          var highscore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(GameUtility.savePrefKey);

          switch (type)
          {
            case ResolutionScreenType.Correct:
              uIElements.ResolutionBG.color = parameters.CorrectBGColour;
              uIElements.ResolutionStateInfoText.text = "Correct!";
              uIElements.ResolutionScoreText.text = "+" + score;
              MusicSource.Play();
              break;
            case ResolutionScreenType.Incorrect:
              uIElements.ResolutionBG.color = parameters.IncorrectBGColour;
              uIElements.ResolutionStateInfoText.text = "Incorrect!";
              uIElements.ResolutionScoreText.text = "-" + score;
              MusicSource_2.Play();
              break;
       }
```

Comment: Did you swap audiclips by chance?

Comment: @Johnny Do you mean in the Unity Inspector? Because I did that and all it did was play the other music clip in both instances (correct and incorrect).

Comment: Rather use only **one** `AudioSource` and use [`PlayOneShot`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayOneShot.html)

Comment: There is no error in code, just make sure correct option is not getting override by incorrect one.

And as derHugo mentioned you can use only one AudioSource use PlayOneShot

Comment: also make sure to `Stop` the according other `AudioSource` you do not want to play anymore